# To authenticate .NET Core 3.0 WPF desktop client with AD B2C, how to use the Default OS Browser?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-ad-msal, .net-core-3.0

I am creating a new WPF .NET Core 3.0 app, using `Microsoft Identity Client (4.0.0)`, and want to authenticate using AD B2C to gain access to a Web API.

I have registered the app with the AD B2C tenant. But the call to `AcquireTokenInteractive` is throwing an exception indicating

> "Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but
>   urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found. Configure http://localhost or
>   http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create
>   the PublicClientApplication object. See
>   https://aka.ms/msal-net-os-browser for details".

```
// Creation of PublicClientApp
// Call to WithRedirectUri is commented out because that redirect URI cannot
// be added during app registration. 
public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp { get; } = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.
    Create(ClientId).
    WithB2CAuthority(Authority).
    // WithRedirectUri("http://localhost").
    Build();
```

```
// Sign-in method logic
await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.ApiScopes).
    WithB2CAuthority(App.Authority).
    WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount).
    ExecuteAsync();
```

On the AD B2C app registration I cannot add custom URI "http://localhost". Is this scenario not supported? What other options can I use?

Here is the Azure portal AD B2C tenant app registration screen for native client
[Native app registration screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOtTD.png)

Comment: Can you please show how you create `PublicClientApp`?

Comment: @tmlye I updated the question with code showing the creation of PublicClientApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2C does not currently support this mode of authentication.

[image]

You can refer to this [document](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-Applications) for the authentication.

Comment: It's a native client (WPF .NET Core 3.0, Desktop), not a Web App/Web API. So the screen is different. It says "Custom Redirect URI" and does not take http://localhost. I will update my question with the app registration screenshot as well.

Comment: @skanv updated the answer. Check if it is helpful for you.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of. I will look into alternatives. Seems like WPF .NET Framework apps are supported but not .NET Core.
[link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/)